# Flutter ProviderNotFoundException with BLoC

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, bloc, provider

I'm trying to do a simple Navigation from my WelcomeScreen to my NavigationScreen. When the Button "Get me in" is pressed, the User should get to the NavigationScreen, but when pressing "ProviderNotFoundException" gets thrown. I don't know, if it acutally has something to do with BLoC or not. Navigation to other Widgets is working. What did I do wrong here?

```
WelcomeScreen.dart
```

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:smooth_page_indicator/smooth_page_indicator.dart';
import 'package:speeddatingapp/UI/Welcome/WelcomePages/Welcome_1.dart';
import 'package:speeddatingapp/UI/Welcome/WelcomePages/Welcome_2.dart';
import 'package:speeddatingapp/UI/Welcome/WelcomePages/Welcome_3.dart';
import 'package:speeddatingapp/UI/Welcome/WelcomePages/Welcome_4.dart';
import 'package:speeddatingapp/domain/entities/classRoutes.dart';
import 'package:speeddatingapp/homemenu/landingPage.dart';
import 'package:speeddatingapp/homemenu/navigation.dart';

import 'bloc/welcome_bloc.dart';

class WelcomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  WelcomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static String route = "Welcome";
  final PageController _controller = PageController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<WelcomeBloc, WelcomeState>(
      bloc: WelcomeBloc(),
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              PageView(
                physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                controller: _controller,
                children: const [
                  WelcomeOne(),
                  WelcomeTwo(),
                  WelcomeThree(),
                  WelcomeFour()
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: const Alignment(0, 0.75),
                child: SmoothPageIndicator(
                  controller: _controller,
                  count: 4,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment(0, 0.90),
                child: CupertinoButton(
                  color: Colors.grey[700],
                  child: Text("Get me in !"),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.popAndPushNamed(
                      context, NavigationScreen.route),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

```
NavigationScreen.dart
```

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:speeddatingapp/UI/Options/SettingsPageUI.dart';
import 'package:speeddatingapp/homemenu/cubit/bottom_navigation_cubit.dart';
import 'package:speeddatingapp/homemenu/home_screen_new.dart';
import 'package:speeddatingapp/homemenu/navbar_items.dart';
import 'package:speeddatingapp/navigator/profileScreen.dart';

int _selectedIndex = 0;

class NavigationScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavigationScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static String route = "Navigator";

  void _onTappedItem(index) {
    _selectedIndex = index;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar:
          BlocBuilder<BottomNavigationCubit, BottomNavigationState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          return BottomNavigationBar(
            currentIndex: state.selectedIndex,
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            items: const [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: "Home"),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.person), label: "Profile"),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.chat), label: "Chat"),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.settings), label: "Settings"),
            ],
            onTap:
                // select different BottomNavigationBarItems
                (index) {
              if (index == 0) {
                BlocProvider.of<BottomNavigationCubit>(context)
                    .getNavBar(NavbarItem.home);
              } else if (index == 1) {
                BlocProvider.of<BottomNavigationCubit>(context)
                    .getNavBar(NavbarItem.profile);
              } else if (index == 2) {
                BlocProvider.of<BottomNavigationCubit>(context)
                    .getNavBar(NavbarItem.chat);
              } else if (index == 3) {
                BlocProvider.of<BottomNavigationCubit>(context)
                    .getNavBar(NavbarItem.settings);
              }
            },
          );
        },
      ),
      body: BlocBuilder<BottomNavigationCubit, BottomNavigationState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state.navbarItem == NavbarItem.home) {
            return const HomeScreenNew();
          } else if (state.navbarItem == NavbarItem.profile) {
            return const ProfileScreen();
          } else if (state.navbarItem == NavbarItem.chat) {
            return const Placeholder();
          } else if (state.navbarItem == NavbarItem.settings) {
            return const SettingPage();
          }
          return Container();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
GetRoutes
```

```
getRoutes() {
  return {
    Login.route: (context) => const Login(),
    Register.route: (context) => const Register(),
    ForgotPassword.route: (context) => const ForgotPassword(),
    TermsOfServicePopUp.route: (context) => const TermsOfServicePopUp(),
    ProfileScreen.route: (context) => const ProfileScreen(),
    LandingPage.route: (context) => const LandingPage(),
    Optionmenu.route: (context) => const Optionmenu(),
    SettingPage.route: (context) => const SettingPage(),
    Preferences.route: (context) => const Preferences(),
    NavigationScreen.route: (context) => const NavigationScreen(),
    WelcomePage.route: (context) =>  WelcomePage()
  };
}
```

```
main.dart
```

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:speeddatingapp/UI/Login/loginContainerBody.dart';
import 'package:speeddatingapp/UI/Login/loginMain.dart';
import 'package:speeddatingapp/UI/Welcome/WelcomePage.dart';
import 'package:speeddatingapp/UI/Welcome/bloc/welcome_bloc.dart';
import 'package:speeddatingapp/domain/entities/classSizeConfig.dart';
import 'package:speeddatingapp/homemenu/cubit/bloc/home_bloc.dart';
import 'package:speeddatingapp/homemenu/cubit/bottom_navigation_cubit.dart';
import 'package:speeddatingapp/homemenu/navigation.dart';
import 'package:speeddatingapp/injection.dart' as di;
import 'package:speeddatingapp/navigator/bloc/profile_screen_bloc.dart';
import 'package:speeddatingapp/navigator/profileScreen.dart';
import 'domain/entities/classRoutes.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await di.init();
  runApp(const SpeedDatingApp());
}

class SpeedDatingApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const SpeedDatingApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Roboto'),
      home: Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          SizeConfig().initState(context);
          return MultiBlocProvider(providers: [
            BlocProvider<ProfileScreenBloc>(
              create: (BuildContext context) => ProfileScreenBloc(),
            ),
            BlocProvider<BottomNavigationCubit>(
                create: (BuildContext context) => BottomNavigationCubit()),
            BlocProvider<HomeBloc>(
              create: (BuildContext context) => HomeBloc(),
            ),
            BlocProvider<WelcomeBloc>(
                create: (BuildContext context) => WelcomeBloc())
          ], child: WelcomePage());
        },
      ),
      routes: getRoutes(),
    );
    //});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the bug by creating Multiblocprovider before Material App:

```
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await di.init();
  runApp(const SpeedDatingApp());
  
}

class SpeedDatingApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const SpeedDatingApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().initState(context);
    return MultiBlocProvider( //Before Material App
        providers: [
          BlocProvider<ProfileScreenBloc>(
            create: (BuildContext context) => ProfileScreenBloc(),
          ),
          BlocProvider<BottomNavigationCubit>(
              create: (BuildContext context) => BottomNavigationCubit()),
          BlocProvider<HomeBloc>(
            create: (BuildContext context) => HomeBloc(),
          ),
          BlocProvider<WelcomeBloc>(
              create: (BuildContext context) => WelcomeBloc())
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
          
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Roboto'),
          home: Login(),
          routes: getRoutes(),
        ));

    //});
  }
}
```